# How would I go about specifying the number of desired contour plot lines, axis values displayed, and specify the overall size of the plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have a working contour plot, but I want to expand its size for better viewing. I want to expand it so that all values on the X and Y axes are visible, and I want to be able to specify the number of contour lines displayed.

Contour plot code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import pylab

# List of points in x axis
XPoints     = [0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,75,80,85,90,95,100]

# List of points in y axis
YPoints     = [0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,75,80,85,90,95,100]

# Z values as a matrix
ZPoints     = [[1650000,1699500,1749000,1798500,1848000,1897500,1947000,1996500,2046000,2095500,2145000,2194500,2244000,2293500,2343000,2392500,2442000,2491500,2541000,2590500,2640000],[1732500,1784475,1836450,1888425,1940400,1992375,2044350,2096325,2148300,2200275,2252250,2304225,2356200,2408175,2460150,2512125,2564100,2616075,2668050,2720025,2772000],[1815000,1869450,1923900,1978350,2032800,2087250,2141700,2196150,2250600,2305050,2359500,2413950,2468400,2522850,2577300,2631750,2686200,2740650,2795100,2849550,2904000],[1897500,1954425,2011350,2068275,2125200,2182125,2239050,2295975,2352900,2409825,2466750,2523675,2580600,2637525,2694450,2751375,2808300,2865225,2922150,2979075,3036000],[1980000,2039400,2098800,2158200,2217600,2277000,2336400,2395800,2455200,2514600,2574000,2633400,2692800,2752200,2811600,2871000,2930400,2989800,3049200,3108600,3168000],[2062500,2124375,2186250,2248125,2310000,2371875,2433750,2495625,2557500,2619375,2681250,2743125,2805000,2866875,2928750,2990625,3052500,3114375,3176250,3238125,3300000],[2145000,2209350,2273700,2338050,2402400,2466750,2531100,2595450,2659800,2724150,2788500,2852850,2917200,2981550,3045900,3110250,3174600,3238950,3303300,3367650,3432000],[2227500,2294325,2361150,2427975,2494800,2561625,2628450,2695275,2762100,2828925,2895750,2962575,3029400,3096225,3163050,3229875,3296700,3363525,3430350,3497175,3564000],[2310000,2379300,2448600,2517900,2587200,2656500,2725800,2795100,2864400,2933700,3003000,3072300,3141600,3210900,3280200,3349500,3418800,3488100,3557400,3626700,3696000],[2392500,2464275,2536050,2607825,2679600,2751375,2823150,2894925,2966700,3038475,3110250,3182025,3253800,3325575,3397350,3469125,3540900,3612675,3684450,3756225,3828000],[2475000,2549250,2623500,2697750,2772000,2846250,2920500,2994750,3069000,3143250,3217500,3291750,3366000,3440250,3514500,3588750,3663000,3737250,3811500,3885750,3960000],[2557500,2634225,2710950,2787675,2864400,2941125,3017850,3094575,3171300,3248025,3324750,3401475,3478200,3554925,3631650,3708375,3785100,3861825,3938550,4015275,4092000],[2640000,2719200,2798400,2877600,2956800,3036000,3115200,3194400,3273600,3352800,3432000,3511200,3590400,3669600,3748800,3828000,3907200,3986400,4065600,4144800,4224000],[2722500,2804175,2885850,2967525,3049200,3130875,3212550,3294225,3375900,3457575,3539250,3620925,3702600,3784275,3865950,3947625,4029300,4110975,4192650,4274325,4356000],[2805000,2889150,2973300,3057450,3141600,3225750,3309900,3394050,3478200,3562350,3646500,3730650,3814800,3898950,3983100,4067250,4151400,4235550,4319700,4403850,4488000],[2887500,2974125,3060750,3147375,3234000,3320625,3407250,3493875,3580500,3667125,3753750,3840375,3927000,4013625,4100250,4186875,4273500,4360125,4446750,4533375,4620000],[2970000,3059100,3148200,3237300,3326400,3415500,3504600,3593700,3682800,3771900,3861000,3950100,4039200,4128300,4217400,4306500,4395600,4484700,4573800,4662900,4752000],[3052500,3144075,3235650,3327225,3418800,3510375,3601950,3693525,3785100,3876675,3968250,4059825,4151400,4242975,4334550,4426125,4517700,4609275,4700850,4792425,4884000],[3135000,3229050,3323100,3417150,3511200,3605250,3699300,3793350,3887400,3981450,4075500,4169550,4263600,4357650,4451700,4545750,4639800,4733850,4827900,4921950,5016000],[3217500,3314025,3410550,3507075,3603600,3700125,3796650,3893175,3989700,4086225,4182750,4279275,4375800,4472325,4568850,4665375,4761900,4858425,4954950,5051475,5148000],[3300000,3399000,3498000,3597000,3696000,3795000,3894000,3993000,4092000,4191000,4290000,4389000,4488000,4587000,4686000,4785000,4884000,4983000,5082000,5181000,5280000]]

# Print x,y and z values
print(XPoints)
print(YPoints)
print(ZPoints)

# Set the x axis and y axis limits
pylab.xlim([0,100])
pylab.ylim([0,100])

# Provide a title for the contour plot
plot.title('Z values label')

# Set x axis label for the contour plot
plot.xlabel('X values label')

# Set y axis label for the contour plot
plot.ylabel('Y values label')

# Create contour lines or level curves using matplotlib.pyplot module
contours = plot.contour(XPoints, YPoints, ZPoints)

# Display z values on contour lines
plot.clabel(contours, inline=1, fontsize=10)

# Display the contour plot
plot.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Was looking in the wrong documentation before.

Using `xlim()` and `ylim()`, I could limit the scope of what's being plotted, and using the attributes available in pylab for `clabel`, I found I could modify my `contours` variable to specify the number of contour lines to draw.

E.g. `contours = plot.contour(XPoints, YPoints, ZPoints, 50`